# VBA return object from function - Object variable or With block variable not set

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to create a macro in Excel VBA.
Get `Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set`

What is wrong here? Isn't that simply supposed to work?

```
Function comeinand() As Object
    Dim screwaround As Object
    Set screwaround = New Collection
    'Also tried:
    'Dim screwaround As New Collection
    'Set screwaround = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    comeinand = screwaround 
End Function
```

Comment: `Set comeinand = screwaround`.